# How do you make a armature and connect it to a mesh?

Tags: animation, armature

I am making a spider and can’t find any YouTube videos on armatures. How do you connect an armature to the spider so I can animate it?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJv68SSdwxip33M7snakl6Dx) is probably the most comprehensive rigging tutorial that you'll find. (Doesn't cover spiders though!)

Comment: After you've made the rig just select the mesh in object mode and then shift click the armature and press cmd+p or ctrl+p and press automatic weights.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an armature ready to go, then in Object mode, select the mesh and then shift select the armature. Then press Cmd+P/Ctrl+P and parent it with automatic weights.

Now you can select the armature and move the individual bones in Pose mode and the mesh should move with it. If certain bones have too much/too little influence on the mesh, you can alter it by selecting the mesh, going to Weight Paint mode, and select the bone that you want to edit in the Object Data Properties tab under Vertex Groups.

It might also be useful to apply some inverse kinematics to your armature to make animation easier and more realistic. Blender has a good video tutorial on how to do that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-2v_CKmVE8) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pt3-mHBCoQk) is also useful.

As mentioned previously, this [YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJv68SSdwxip33M7snakl6Dx) is a really helpful resource that walks through almost every aspect of adding and editing armatures.

Comment: Ctrl+P seems to do nothing for me. Any suggestions?